# How to represent n-ary tree in 2D matrix?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, treeview, language-agnostic

I am trying to represent an n-ary tree in an 2D matrix. Not sure how to approach the problem. This would be some sort of hierarchy. I have the root node of the tree

Example : [image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Since you are not asking about a C++ problem, I switched to the language-agnostic tag.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking for. As somebody else suggested, the adjacency matrix is a pretty standard way to represent trees or graphs in a matrix. If this is a strict n-ary tree, then you can easily represent it in a one-dimensional array using the same technique used to represent a binary (or n-ary) heap, although the representation will be very sparse if the tree is not full and balanced.

Comment: What is the purpose of this representation? The example you show seems to me unuseful except possibly as a visual representation (and not the best one, either). If you want to use the data structure in order to do some kind of tree analysis, then there are much more efficient and usable data structures, and it would be useful to know what sort of analyses you are interested in.

Comment: *"I am trying to"*: please edit your question and show your attempt, and explain what the problem is. The matrix looks like the result of a pre-order traversal of the tree. It is not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table represents a pre-order (depth-first) traversal. You can implement it with a recursive function.

Pseudo code:

```py
function dfs(children, row=0, col=0):
    if no children:
        return row + 1  # It is a leaf
    for each child in children:
        output child.label in table(row, col)
        row = dfs(child.children, row, col + 1)
    return row   # It was not a leaf
```

Here is an implementation in JavaScript, with output to an HTML table:

```js
function output(label, row, col) {
    document.querySelector("table").rows[row].cells[col].textContent = label;
}

function dfs(children, row=0, col=0) {
    if (!children?.length) return row + 1; // End of path
    for (const child of children) {
        output(child.label, row, col);
        row = dfs(child.children, row, col + 1);
    }
    return row; // It was not a leaf
}

// Example tree:
const forest = [
    { "label": "a", "children": [
        { "label": "b", "children": [
            { "label": "j" },
            { "label": "k" },
        ]},
        { "label": "c" },
        { "label": "d", "children": [
            { "label": "e" },
            { "label": "f", "children": [
                { "label": "h" },
                { "label": "i" },
            ]},
            { "label": "g" },
        ]}
    ]}
];

dfs(forest);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
table td { border: 1px solid; width: 20%; padding-left: 10px }
tr { height: 25px; v-align: middle; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```